# sftp показывает имена файлов через \301\356

Tags: linux, sftp

Система `Debian`. при попытки подключится имена русских файлов как в вопросе.
Windows отображает все нормально. Кодировка сервера utf8

```
~$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Подключаюсь

```
 sftp -oPort=22122 -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@example.ru:/path
```

*Задача:* копирование папки на публичный сервер в личную директорию, в инструкции указана работа через `WINSCP`. Я же хочу сделать это скриптом, после того как закончится другой скрип. Так как сервер публичный, папки в который происходит копирование может и не быть.

Comment: 1. вывод программы *locale* (до запуска программы *sftp*) приложите к вопросу, нажав [edit]. 2. если возможно, лучше монтировать каталог с помощью программы *sshfs*

Comment: `$ echo -e '\0301\0356' | iconv -f cp1251` показывает `Бо`. так что, судя по всему, у вас всё в порядке: вы, вероятно, используете ftp, значит, надо привыкать к его неизлечимым проблемам. для этой древней окаменелости «это» — абсолютно нормально.

Comment: sftp это не ftp